# Force IOS/android user to check the notification

Tags: android, ios, push-notification

I am developing a IOS/android app which will used by our vendors, the app will send notifications to the vendors timely, i wonder if there is a way that the vendor MUST click "accept" or "read" for every notification, even he/she disable the notification permission for this app.

so, all of my perpose is the vendor must ready the notification and the server side should be able to know who is not read. the vendors should not has an execuse that he/she do not get a notice while the policy changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to 'force' a user to open a notification, but if you use a Push Notification service (AppBoy, etc) most of them have metrics and can track who has opened the notifications. So if your vendor comes back and says they never got it, you can say yes you did, and which device they opened it on. You could then continually send notifications to those who haven't opened it until they do.

This won't work if they have notifications disabled, though. No way to get past that without building a messaging system into your app.

Comment: build a message system, you mean query to the back end server timely?

Comment: Yes, basically inside the app you poll for new messages from your sever. You would need to create the API on your server that returns the messages, and have the app send along it's vendor ID so you know if that person has already received the message. Then you keep displaying that message to the user until they interact with it in some way. (Maybe daily)